# Rails application is not using my xls view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, excel, haml

I having the following action:

```
def users_report
  @users = Kid.where(confirmation_token: nil).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xls { send_data @users.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
  end
end
```

Also I have two views "users_report.html.haml" and "users_report.xls.erb", but when I pressed the button to export to excel I get the file users_report.xls but I can only see objects, but the users_report.xls.erb has his structure all the fields order by columns.

Can anyone help me here, please?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE XLS VIEW

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Surname</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Email</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Age</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">School</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Class</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Native Language</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Practised Language</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Conversations same Native</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Convserations different Native</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Message same Native</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Message different Native</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Posts</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Videos watched</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Clossed/Finished calls</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Missed calls</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Connections per Week</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Nb of foreign friends</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Nb of friends same country</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Activation Date</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Email Parent</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Parent Activated</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.name rescue _("No name") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.surname rescue _("No surname") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.email rescue _("No email") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.age rescue _("No age") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.school.name rescue _("No School") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.courses.first.name rescue _("No Course") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= sentence_native_languages_of user rescue _("No native language") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= sentence_practise_languages_of user rescue _("No practise language") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.number_of_native_conversations rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.number_of_foreign_conversations rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.number_of_native_messages rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.number_of_foreign_messages rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.number_of_activity_posts rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.number_of_finished_closed_calls rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.number_of_missed_calls rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= number_with_precision(user.avg_of_connections_week, precision: 3) rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.number_of_foreign_friends rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.number_of_friends_same_country rescue _("0") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.confirmed_at.try(:strftime, "%d/%m/%Y") %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.tutor.email rescue _('No parent email') %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= user.tutor.confirmed? rescue _('No parent email') %></Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: "has his structure all the fields order by columns" can you clarify that part please?

Comment: I mean, on my users_report.xls.erb I made the estructure of the excel file

Comment: So the users_report.xls is full of stuff like `#<User:0x007f8f3deb04f0>` rather than strings representing the stored data, like the user's first and last name?

Comment: Correct ecnalyr, sorry about my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action to something like:

```
format.xls { send_data Kid.to_csv({col_sep: "\t"}, @users) }
```

You should not have to change anything in your view.

Comment: Thanks Ecnalyr,  but I get the same data, only #<User:0x007f8f3deb04f0>

Comment: @Jean I had the wrong information in there a moment ago, do you get the error with `format.xls { send_data User.to_csv({col_sep: "\t"}, @users) } }` still?

Comment: yes, I get the following error: uninitialized constant Admin::HomeController::User

Comment: What is the name of the model being stored in `@users` ? I assumed it was `User` but that seems to be incorrect here.  You need to change `User` to the class of the objects within `@users`.

Comment: Kid, but I try and the the same error but with kid....uninitialized constant Admin::HomeController::Kid

Comment: It's ok, I was a problem with my to_csv method on my model. Thanks I'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49740/discussion-between-ecnalyr-and-jean)

Answer (score 0):

Add the xls mime type to your config/initilizers/mime_types.rb file:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls
```